# Prove $\sum_{i=1}^n{(-1)^{i(i-1)/2}}$ is bounded

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, induction

I tried to prove this using Mathematical Induction (omitting base step):

Inductive step:

If ${\sum_{i=1}^n{(-1)^{i(i-1)/2 } \le 1}}$ then ${\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{(-1)^{i(i-1)/2 } \le 1}}$

But at this point, I got stuck when arguing what happens when (n+1)n/2 is even. So I tried a different aproach: I realized that if you take 4 consecutive terms and add them, you get zero no matter how you choose those terms. This, plus making use of complete induction, could let me say that:

${\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{(-1)^{i(i-1)/2 } = {\sum_{i=1}^{n-3}{(-1)^{i(i-1)/2  }\le1} } }}$

However I did not found a way to prove this, and maybe I am just going the wrong way with this making it harder than what it should be.

Any help/hint would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If $n=1$ the sum is $1+1=2$, yes?  So the bound should be $2$, not $1$.

Comment: To prove the induction step with the adding of $4$ terms, you may want to use modular arithmetic.

Comment: It was intended to start in i=1, but the problem is the same. I'll correct it now.

Comment: Well, if you start at $i=1$ then $1$ is indeed the upper bound.

Comment: when is $i(i-1)/2$ even ? when is it odd ?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{i(i-1)}2=\underbrace{1+2+3+4+\dots}_{i-1}$$ should help with the even/odd problem.

Comment: @SimpleArt if $i \equiv 0 \bmod 4$ then $i (i-1)/2$ is even, the same if $i \equiv 1 \bmod 4$. if $i \equiv 2$ or $3 \bmod 4$ then $i(i-1)/2$ is odd.

Comment: @user1952009 Realized the summation form was easier to understand.

Comment: easier than $\frac{4n(4n-1)}{2} = 2n(4n-1)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\frac{i(i-1)}2=\sum_{n=1}^{i-1}n=1+2+3+\dots(n-1)$$

It is easy to see that for $i>1$, every $4$ terms will have $2$ even and $2$ odd terms.  Since $(-1)^n$ will cancel with itself every four terms, the problem reduces by induction down to the bounds of

$$\sum_{i=1}^{1,2,3,4}(-1)^{i(i-1)/2}$$

which can be easily calculated.